# Is it possible to get Microsoft Exchange Online Transport Rules (Email server-side rules) and apply them locally to my Outlook desktop messages?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office365, office365api

I am trying to write an Add-in to Outlook 2016 and I want server-side rules (Transport rules, aka Mail Workflow) to be applied to my Outlook email locally not on Exchange online. The concept of My my Add-In is next: download server-side rules , apply to an email and send it.
The maximum I have achieved was connecting to Exchange Online server and using Get methods in PowerShell to download server rules. I did not find related API only old VBA Outlook 2007
Is there any API to do so? Are there any other ways to do so?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are no automated ways to convert or export transport rules to client/Outlook rules.  However, the Outlook Object Model (OOM) has good support for creating and managing Outlook rules via VBA, a COM add-in or a custom desktop application using OOM.  The actions and conditions may not be 100% identical but you should be able to convert the majority of rules.  See: [Managing Rules in the Outlook Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff860622.aspx).